# How to replace multiple words of a string using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a dictionary like:

```
dic = { "xl": "xlarg", "l": "larg",'m':'medium'}
```

and I'd like to use re.sub or similar methods find any string (including a single letter) which are in dic.keys and replace it with the key's value.

```
def multiple_replace(dict, text):
     # Create a regular expression  from the dictionary keys
     regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))
    
     # For each match, look-up corresponding value in dictionary
     return regex.sub(lambda mo: dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text)
```

it works well for single letters in the string e.g. it changes size m to size medium but also it changes letters in words, e.g changes monday to mediumonday

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some samples along with expected output?

Comment: You can use a lookahead where your single word character is followed by a *not* word character: `"(%s)(?=\W)"` where `(?=....)` is lookahead and `\W` (capital W) means not word character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.compile` and the `sub` method to find the matching substrings and replace them. The idea here is that you join all of the keys into a single pattern by using an OR statement `|`. For each match you then use the matched substring to do a lookup on the replacement dict.

Along with this you can use a lookbehind and a lookahead regex. For the lookbehind, you want it to not be a word `(?<!\w)`. For the lookahead, you want it to also not be word `(?!\w)`.

Putting this altogether, we have: `r"(?<!\w)(xl|l|m)(?!\w)"`

Here's an example:

```
def replace_substrings(s, d):
    p = "|".join(d.keys())
    p = r"(?<!\w)(" + p + r")(?!\w)"
    return re.compile(p).sub(lambda m: d[m.group(0)], s)
...


dic = {"xl": "xlarg", "l": "larg",'m':'medium'}
inputs = [
    "size m",
    "monday",
    "xl sell",
    "m size m l xl",
]

for input in inputs:
    print(replace_substrings(input, dic))
```

This will output:

```
size medium
monday
xlarg sell
medium size medium larg xlarg
```

Comment: This is what the OP does *not* want.

Comment: @JohanL I fixed it, please take another look